# Convert powershell commands that download zip file from sharepoint url to python

Tags: python, c#, powershell, sharepoint

As the title suggests I need to convert powershell commands that successfully downloaded a zip file from a sharepoint url (I've replaced sensitive information in the sharepoint url with 'xxx') to python.

Using the powershell in Windows to download a zip file from url works like a charm.

```
 > $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 > $client.Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer eyJ...")
 > $DownloadFilePath = "C:\path\to\file.zip"
 > $FileUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"
 > $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $DownloadFilePath)
```

If I execute the below command in powershell

```
> $value
```

I get no output, which means that $value is not a variable that contains anything. However, it is necessary in the url in order to produce a non-empty local zip file, using powershell commands.

Now, using python to download a zip file -- given the same url and token as above -- does not work. The code below produces a 400 error and an empty zip file.

```py
import requests
FileUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ..."
}
r = requests.get(FileUrl, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
with open(r"C:\path\to\file.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is the FileUrl correct? `FileUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"` ?

Comment: I've replaced sensitive information in the sharepoint url with 'xxx'

Comment: That's fine, I am more concerned about the end - `(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"`, this seems odd?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on. ```xxx``` would be the sharepoint site and ```path/to/file.zip``` would be the relative path to the zip file from the sharepoint site.

Comment: The `\`` in `\`$value` _escapes the `$` character_ inside the `"..."` PowerShell string, to that `$value` is used _verbatim_ rather than interpreted as a _variable reference_ and replaced by the variable's value. Do not use the `\`` in Python.

Comment: Variables in Python do not start with $. Try changing $value to value.  Also see mklemetnt0 comment above.

Comment: String concatenation is also also different. Try `"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/" + "value"`

Comment: This line confuses me.  "If I execute the below command in powershell  ; $value"  if you changed to If "I execute the below command in python ; value"  it would make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. Removing the powershell escape character ` from the url for the python implementation fixed the problem.